# How do I use CultureInfo to get the 12-hour or 24-hour time (without the date)

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, cultureinfo

I would like to use C# to format a time of day in the proper cultural format.

For example, if the current culture is en-US I would like to show 1:00 PM, and if the current culture is fr-FR I would like to show 13:00. I just want the time of day, I do not want the date.

```
//timeOfDay is a DateTime object.

//This will return the 12 hour clock regardless of culture:
time = timeOfDay.ToString("h:mm tt", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
//This will return the 24 hour clock regardless of culture
time = timeOfDay.ToString("H:mm tt", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
//This will return the correct clock for the culture, but the date will also be present
time = timeOfDay.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Note that the "tt" is for AM/PM, and it is culturally sensitive (in France it is blank, as it should be).

How do I acquire the appropriate clock format for the current culture, without the date?

Comment: Please take a look at [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings).

Comment: Have you tried `.ToShortTimeString()`? If that's not satisfactory for your case then you could work with the `DateTimeFormatInfo` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo?view=netframework-4.7.1

Comment: @Jasen ToShortTimeString() works, and is more concise than other methods. If you make it an answer I will mark it accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to be explicit you could use `.ToShortTimeString()` and let the system determine the format.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshorttimestring(v=vs.110).aspx

> The string returned by the ToShortTimeString method is culture-sensitive. It reflects the pattern defined by the current culture's DateTimeFormatInfo object. For example, for the en-US culture, the standard short time pattern is **"h:mm tt"**; for the de-DE culture, it is **"HH:mm"**; for the ja-JP culture, it is **"H:mm"**. The specific format string on a particular computer can also be customized so that it differs from the standard short time format string.

The emphasis is mine.

---

Edit to demonstrate for this use case:

```
//ToShortTimeString automatically uses current culture to show hour:minute
string time = timeOfDay.ToShortTimeString();
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```
string time = timeOfDay.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

The second parameter is probably unnecessary as well.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see any other option to check [`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture) information and format `timeOfDay` differently (because your strings have different formats) based on *that* culture.

```
if (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture == new CultureInfo("en-US"))
{
    time = timeOfDay.ToString("h:mm tt", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}

if (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture == new CultureInfo("fr-FR"))
{
    time = timeOfDay.ToString("HH:mm", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

Comment: This answer is unnecessarily cumbersome - it doesn't make use of the format info within CurrentCulture object - and inherently *incomplete*, as it is not practical to list *all* possible cultures. (Consider deleting it.)